# Mongo / PHP wrapper error - how do i get the wrapper working?

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm getting this error when trying to connect to a mongo server:

```
Unable to find the wrapper "mongodb" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

The connection string looks like this:

```
$conn = new Mongo("mongodb://XXXX:XXXX@XXX.member0.mongohq.com:10021/XXX",array("replicaSet" => 'rsname'));
```

I tried finding out qhat wrappers were available using:

```
var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());
```

and got the following:

```
array
  0 => string 'https' (length=5)
  1 => string 'ftps' (length=4)
  2 => string 'compress.zlib' (length=13)
  3 => string 'compress.bzip2' (length=14)
  4 => string 'php' (length=3)
  5 => string 'file' (length=4)
  6 => string 'glob' (length=4)
  7 => string 'data' (length=4)
  8 => string 'http' (length=4)
  9 => string 'ftp' (length=3)
  10 => string 'phar' (length=4)
  11 => string 'zip' (length=3)
  12 => string 'ssh2.shell' (length=10)
  13 => string 'ssh2.exec' (length=9)
  14 => string 'ssh2.tunnel' (length=11)
  15 => string 'ssh2.scp' (length=8)
  16 => string 'ssh2.sftp' (length=9)
```

I've  checked the conf.d folders and they all seem to be in order form what I can see, so i'm not sure what I need to do to allow me to connect using the wrapper, as the example shows in the php docs example.

I'm running nginx / PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.11

Ha anyone delat with this before, or able to offer some guidance? Thanks.

Comment: *"Unable to find the wrapper "mongodb" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"* What is your answer to that question?

Comment: I'm not sure is my answer :) I've tried looking everywhere to find out HOW to install it, and I have not yet found an answer. I guess that is part of my question here too. How do I enable the wrapper?

Comment: There is no such stream wrapper called `mongodb`. The connection string in your code looks fine. Are you using Zend Framework? Check this: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/2446 - Please add information to your question which file and line of code is giving that error.

Comment: No, im using Kohana, but i'll have a look at the Zend stuff, it might just offer up a solution for me.

Comment: I tired implementing the Zend example, and seeing if it would work in Kohana as well, but it didn't like it, as the php MOngo::__construct looks to be wanting the paramater as a string, and the Zend example seems to return an object

Comment: As written, add the file and line of code that triggers the error. Is that in kohana sources?

Comment: Do you have the PHP Mongo extension installed? If not, then `sudo pecl install mongo`

Comment: Yep, definitely checked that step first. I hate it when it's the most obvious things you forget to check :)

Comment: @hakre it's not a core Kohana issue, it's just a handrolled piece of code, unlike the Zend example. I might have to try and find a workaround.

Comment: You mean the error is triggered by that line of code in your question? That line: `$conn = new Mongo("mongodb://XXXX:XXXX@XXX.member0.mongohq.com:10021/XXX",array("replicaSet" => 'rsname'));`? - I ask, because as far as I know MongoDB is totally unrelated to stream wrappers. But your error is about a stream wrapper. Something takes the connection string and opens a file or similar with it. For example I can provoke this error like so: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6RVGIu - Check if there are additional errors and the file and line of code the error is given.

Comment: That's looking pretty much like what i'm getting. I'm using the raw PHP functions, not some overlaying library, so (to the best of my knowledge) there's nothing that is handling that string in between it being passed to the core PHP function. I'll do some more testing and look for other code errors. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Mongo php library are you using? 
I made a simple test like this using version 1.2.12:

```
<?php

$mongo = new Mongo('mongodb://host1.local:27019,host2.local:27020', array("replicaSet"=>'aaa'));

$hosts = $mongo->getHosts();

var_dump( $hosts );
?>
```

and got absolutely no problem.
ReplicaSet support through the php driver is available since request [PHP-121](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-121) which goes back to version 1.0.9

To be more concrete on answering your question, the mongo php driver does not use a connection wrapper. It has a connection parser. You can find more detailled info in the code itself:
[parser.c](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/mcon/parse.c#L35)

PS: Your ubuntu version is a bit old! Was released in 10/2007 and reached EOL on the 4/2009.

Comment: I'm using the latest beta version of the mongo driver, was one of the steps I tried in case it was something to do with my driver.

Comment: I'm not sure my ubuntu is that old.. 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=natty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.04"

Comment: I might try an example like yours outside of anything Kohana may be touching. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: OK, so my test in raw PHP has now given me a different error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'No candidate servers found' in /root/test.php:3` which is annoying, and another hurdle for me, but at least i'm not getting the error as before, which to me indicates it's likely a Kohana derived error. Thanks people!

Comment: ok, my mistake on the ubuntu version, I've got the wrong impression you where running version 7.11.

Comment: HA! Don't worry, you had me worried there for a second too :)

Comment: OK, i've managed to work around the issue, to get the same result. Using the 'options' array to pass the username and password rather than using a full connection string as in the example above allows me to do the replicaSet connection without errors. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.construct.php Thanks for suggestions as it put me on the right track.